# Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib'

Tags: sql, sql-server, macos, sql-server-2008, odbc

I am trying to get mssql working on my OSX machine. However, it keeps giving me error:

```
$ sqlcmd -S 0.0.0.0,1401 -U SA -P P@55w0rd -i database-setup/sql/initialize.sql
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found.
```

Although, I am pretty sure, my file is in that location:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 localadmin  admin  64  7  4 16:38 /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib

$ ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 localadmin  admin  2539360  7  4 15:34 /usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

I know this question has been asked multiple times but none of the available solutions have worked for me.
Things I have tried:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/7
- https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/3

Comment: that "file" is a symlink. Can you check if the file it points to exists as well? What does e.g. "file /usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib" print?

Comment: It does. ```$ ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 localadmin  admin  2539360  7  4 15:34 /usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib```

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 8):

I fixed my problem by:

```
$ brew uninstall msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

and then:

```
$ brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Comment: Note that the first command throws `Error: No available formula or cask with the name "msodbcsql17".`.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solved it:

`brew install microsoft/mssql-release/msodbcsql17`